# What does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\cos(1))^{n}$ converge to?

Tags: calculus

> What does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\cos(1))^{n}$ converge to?

I need hints on calculating the sum. If it is not convergent, please tell me why.

Comment: Hint: It's a geometric series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

1. $|\cos(1)| < 1$.
2. Geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$
S_k := \sum_{n=0}^{k} x^n.  
$$
Then 
$$
x S_k = x\sum_{n=0}^{k} x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{k+1} x^n.
$$
So $xS_k-S_k = (x-1)S_k = x^{k+1}-1$ implies 
$$
S_k = \frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1} \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ for }x\not=1. 
$$
Now apply the limit to both sides: 
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} S_k = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1} = \frac{1}{1-x}  \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ for }|x|<1. 
$$
Since 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} S_k, 
$$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(1)^n = \frac{1}{1-\cos (1)}. 
$$

Comment: Thank you, but I was not looking for the solution.