# How to prove that $ 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots = \frac 1{1-x}$ where $|x| < 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

> How to prove that $ 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots = \frac 1{1-x}$ where $|x| < 1$?

I guess I fail to see how one can prove this.  Sorry if duplicate or perhaps there is a website with how to prove results for the not well-behaved infinite sequences.

Comment: I proved this in the first several lines in my solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382965/what-does-sum-n-0-infty-cos1n-converge-to/2382991#2382991 Maybe you can work out the details and check your solution against what I wrote.

Comment: cancellation helps...

Comment: @Sedumjoy You can show the equality for the above using the method in the above link or use MacLaurin series (see below).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of $\sum\limits_n x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/value-of-sum-limits-n-xn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the concept of [Taylor/Maclaurin series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) and is based on the formula

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a) \, (x-a)^n}{n!}$$

where $f^{(n)}(a)$ is the $n$th derivative of $f$ at $a$. Evaluate this for $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and $a=0$ and you will have your answer.

It’s worth noticing that this sum looks like it would diverge because each term is of a higher degree than the previous. However, for fractional $x$, each term actually gets *smaller*, so the series *converges*.

Comment: The Taylor series does tell that one has for *some* neighborhood of $x=0$, 
$\sum x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$. How do you show that the series is valid for *all* $x$ with $|x|<1$?

Comment: @Jack Off the top of my head and without trying it on paper, I suppose one could use the ratio test to determine the interval of convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Using \begin{equation}
1+x+x^2+...+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
\end{equation} for all $x$ and all natural $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$ for $|x|<1$ yields the desired equality.